# Delete third party cookies with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to delete some cookies from my site.

This works fine for custom cookies that I have created e.g.

```
document.cookie = "show-pop-up=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
```

However, I am unable to remove third party cookies (e.g. from Google Analytics) e.g.

```
document.cookie = "__utmz=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
```

Testing in Chrome and attempting to remove a cookie in this way seems to have no effect as I can still see the cookie listed in the application/cookies panel).

Is this possible ?

Thanks,

Comment: I hope you did a refresh, in top left.

Comment: I did yes but the cookie remains.

Comment: I think the nature of Cookies is that they can only be modified (and I guess destroyed) by the site that generated them.  I believe, to limit the ability for malicious use of Cookies

Comment: This may be some interesting follow-up reading material: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/12/cookies-and-security/

Answer (score -1):

google analytics cookies are stored with the domain name minus the www part.
so you can use following code to delete all your cookies.

```
function deleteAllCookies(){
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i];
            var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
            var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;

                document.cookie = name + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/;domain=";
                /*below line is to delete the google analytics cookies. they are set with the domain*/
                document.cookie = name + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/;domain=" + location.hostname.replace(/^www\./i, "");

        }
    }
```

Comment: I doubt you can delete 3rd-party cookies. Would be a massive security concern. It would basically mean that you can access any cookies cross-websites via one specific site.

Comment: I think in the end the better solution is for the browser itself to handle, displaying the notice rather than the website. So we attempt to set cookies, and the browser displays something like **this website wants to set cookies, this is safe but you can still block cookies, however if you do block cookies this website may not function as expected**. if they do decline, the browser simply overrides the time for all cookies and sets a past time so they delete on close of website/browser, because the EU regulations specify its only persistent cookies we need be concerned with.